# Unable to get correct result YouTube search using YouTube Data API v3 by using order 'Date'

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?parts=snippet&q=goodmorningharshit&order=date&key=...`

Output is below, `resultsPerPage` is 2:

```
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
      "etag": "VLFWh8LREU_ROevvLtQi91FgVak",
      "regionCode": "IN",
      "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 31,
        "resultsPerPage": 2
      },
      "items": [
        ...
      ]
    }
```

but, if we remove the `order` parameter, the `resultsPerPage` is getting 6.

Is there any solution to get all data with `order` set to `date`?

Comment: The second call to [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) produces 5 items with `resultsPerPage` being 5, not 6. This is correct, as per the specification.

Comment: I confirm the output produced by the first call to `Search.list`: indeed, when given `order=date`, the API returns only 2 items, with `resultsPerPage` being 2.

Comment: I deem this to be a bug of the API. Therefore, am recommending to file a report directly to Google, through its [own issue tracker site](https://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: thanks @stvar yes it is... hope it'll solve soon.

Comment: @AnkurShukla if this [ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/199184257) the issue you posted? - please, [edit] the question and add the link if the issue.